# how do you update an ADO.NET entity data model when the database tables structure has been modified in vs11

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am creating ado.net entity frameworks from table from by database. Because i am ina early stage i need to chnage the table structure quite often to add or remove fields.

how do you update an ADO.NET entity data model when the database tables structure has been modified in vs11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will right click into the designer pane (not on entity) and select *Update model from database* from context menu.

Comment: that will update the edmx file for sure but it is iffy whether or not the templates regenerate the code for the new items. Havw had many problems with this lately

Answer (score 0):

Open your Project...

Go to Tools Menu > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console

To install EntityFramework, run the following command

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

Hope this help you...